# When user input is "wrong", tell it

Tags: java

Here is my code right now. I really have been looking through the entire thing but cant for the sake of my life find out where the problem that casues the code not to work in my favor is at:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DogGompundTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean dogFound = false;
        boolean toEnd = false;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Dog> dogRegister = new ArrayList<Dog>();

        //Other dogs in program 
        Dog d2 = new Dog("Mira", "Miniature Schnauzer", 1, 8.0, 0.8);
        dogRegister.add(d2);
        Dog d3 = new Dog("Jack", "Jack Russell", 3, 6.0, 1.8);
        dogRegister.add(d3);
        Dog d4 = new Dog("Charlie", "Pug", 5, 5.0, 2.5);
        dogRegister.add(d4);
        Dog d5 = new Dog("Max", "Dachshund", 9, 5.0, 3.7);
        dogRegister.add(d5);
        Dog d6 = new Dog("Bingo", "Golden Retriever", 5, 12.0, 6.0);
        dogRegister.add(d6);

        System.out.println("Name - Race - Age - Weight - Taillength: " + dogRegister);

        while (toEnd == false) {
            System.out.println(
                "\nWhat would you like to do? \n Press 1 to register a dog. \n Press 2 to get a " +
                    "look at the taillengths of the dogs. \n Press 3 to delete a dog from " +
                    "the register.\n Press 4 to quit.");
            int command = keyboard.nextInt(); //Alternatives stored in "command"
            keyboard.nextLine();
            switch (command) { //Execute chosen command in switch-statement
                case 1: //User registers a dog 
                    Dog d1 = new Dog("", "", 0, 0.0, 0.0);
                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the dogs name:");
                    String Name = keyboard.next();
                    d1.setName(Name);

                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the dogs race (in English):");
                    String Race = keyboard.next();
                    d1.setRace(Race);

                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the dogs age (years):");
                    int age = keyboard.nextInt();
                    d1.setage(age);

                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the dogs weight in kg:");
                    double weight = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    d1.setweight(weight);

                    dogRegister.add(d1);
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    System.out.println(
                        "\nComplete dog information: " + "\nName: " + Name + "\nRace: " + Race
                            + "\nAge: " + age + "\nWeight: " + weight + " kg");
                    System.out.println(dogRegister);
                    break;
                case 2: //User gets to see the different taillengths of the dogs in the register

                    System.out.println(
                        "\nEnter taillength and all dogs with a greater taillength will be displayed: ");
                    double taillength = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    for (int index = 0; index < dogRegister.size(); index++) {
                        if (taillength <= (dogRegister.get(index).gettaillength())) {
                            System.out.println(dogRegister.get(index));
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 3: //User deletes a dog from the register
                    System.out.println("State the name of the dog you wish to delete from the register: ");
                    String delete = keyboard.nextLine();
                    for (int del = 0; del < dogRegister.size(); del++) {
                        if (delete.equalsIgnoreCase(dogRegister.get(del).getName())) {
                            System.out.println("\nThe dog with the given name has been deleted from the register.");
                            dogFound = true;
                            dogRegister.remove(del);
                            System.out.print(dogRegister + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                    {
                        if (!dogFound)
                            ;
                        System.out.println("A dog by that name is not registered in our system.");
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("\nThe program has now ended.");
                    toEnd = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should rethink your algorithm, especially check the javadoc for the class you are using for ``dogRegister`` - I suppose it is something inherited from ``java.util.Collection``. There is already anything you need. You should also give all relevant information (necessary type definitions and sample data) to reproduce your problem. Maybe somebody will than investigate into it.

Comment: `dogFound = false` evaluates to `false`, so the `println` won't print. Instead, you want `!dogFound` or `dogFound == false`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `else { }` block outside your loop and use a second variable to determine if an existing dog was found, then set it to true.  Then your `else { }` block instead reads, `if(!dogFound) { }`

Otherwise your code will print the "not found" line whenever it encounters every dog that isn't the one being looked for, as I'm sure you are seeing.  e.g.

```
dogs = ["Jack","Pooch","Fido","Fluffy"]
```

If you try to remove "Fluffy" the execution would look like this:

```
"Jack"  isn't "Fluffy", print "not found."
"Pooch" isn't "Fluffy", print "not found."
"Fido"  isn't "Fluffy", print "not found."
"Fluffy"  is  "Fluffy", remove and print "removed."
```

Comment: Ah, now you just have a syntactical problems.  You have an `else{}` that shouldn't be there (no matching if, empty block), you have an `if()` check wrapped around an assignment (don't do that), and your whitespace that makes the code easily legible is messed up.

Comment: Thank you for helping me and my output is getting "better". When I write the name of a dog it deletes it but now when I write the name of a non-existent dog it doesn't print anything. I've edited my first post again.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting issues with your code [here](http://pastebin.com/Vsr8JAtq).  That will help you figure out what is going wrong, as there is still something inside the `for` loop that shouldn't be and I said you had to move.

Comment: Well, I've really poured my heart into this one you could say..I have tried but haven't figured out how to move it out of the loop..:(

Comment: Im sorry but now it just says var cant be resolved to a variable and other stuff..dogFound is a duplicate and so on..I appreciate all teh help but i've actually been wokring with this problem for four straight hours so im gonna give up and fail my presentation tommorrow

Comment: If you have `dogFound` declared somewhere else, you don't need that line from my code.

Comment: I have it declared at the top of my code boolean dogFound = false;

Comment: Ok, then removing that line from my paste should work.  If it doesn't update your question again.

Comment: `if (dogFound = false)` is still inside the loop and is also using assignment not comparison.

Comment: That's the most important point. Don't use `dogFound = false`. Use `!dogFound`. That alone will fix your problem.

Comment: @Draco18s   I've updated my code. I looked up assignment/comparison still cant figure it out why it doesnt print anything when user inputs a "invalid name".

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I've updated my code. I looked up assignment/comparison still cant figure it out why it doesnt print anything when user inputs a "invalid name".

Comment: `if (!dogFound)` is still inside the loop.  Watch your braces.

Comment: At this point, what is the program doing that it shouldn't, or should and isn't?

Comment: @Draco18s It's doing everything just as I want. The only thing it's doing that I dont like is the fact that it doesnt print out "A dog by that name is not registered in our system." Instead the "menu" jsut pops again. Which it should, but first it should print "A dog by that..:"

Comment: @Draco18s Got any ideas?

Comment: @Draco18s Updated code. Now it prints "A dog by that name was not.." when I enter an invalid name. But when i enter an existing dogs name it prints that too..hmm..Also if i delete "all the dogFound " in the code it doesnt affect the output so i feel as if that has no real effect

Comment: @Caggen Why have you added a `;` to the `if` and what do you think is his "effect"?

Comment: @Tom Well, not quite sure about the "effect" part. Regarding the ";". When I include it it prints "a dog by that name is not reg.." both when i enter a existing and non-existing dogs name. When I now took it away, it doesnt print "a dog by that name is not reg.." when i enter a existing dogs name which is good. But it doesnt do it when i enter an invalid dogs name either : (

Comment: @Caggen When you don't know what it does, then why you've added it there? It should do that if the dog to delete cannot be found. Or you have another/new problem there.

Comment: @Tom Suppose you're right. feels like i've tried everything. Been dealing with this problem for about eight straight hours now and its getting late so dont really know what to do hehe

Comment: @Caggen Then get some rest and work later on it, when you have a clear mind. ;P

Comment: @Tom Hehe prob a good idea. Up early in a couple of hours..Thanks for the help anyways!!